# What is $\int_\infty^\infty f(x)/x \ dx$ where $f(x) \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: integration

Consider $\int_a^{a\cdot t} \frac{f(x)}{x}  \ dx$ where $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$, and $t > 1$. What is the limit of this as $a \rightarrow \infty$?

"Obviously" the limit is zero, since the integrand is going to zero, and we are taking the integral over regions where the integrand is getting closer and closer to zero. But what is the formal way to show this?

Comment: It's not obvious, since the integration interval also gets wider. For instance, if we had allowed $f(x)=1$, then the answer would certainly not be $0$, as $\int_a^{at}\frac1x\,dx$ doesn't change at all as $a$ increases.

Comment: @Arthur, the question states that $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. The function $f(x)=1$ doesn't fit that...

Comment: Do you know when you can interchange limit and integral?

Comment: @Pspl Which is the exact reason I posted it as a comment, not an answer (did you see where I said "if we had allowed $f(x)=1$"?) I was addressing the use of the word "obviously", which I feel is incorrect; the integrand going to $0$ is not enough, and it is _not_ obvious, as my example demonstrates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$, then there is some $N_{\varepsilon}>0$ such that $$x>N_{\varepsilon} \implies |f(x)|<\varepsilon$$

Multiply by $1/x$ and integrate from $a$ to $at$ (assuming that $a>N_{\varepsilon}$), you'll get 
$$-\varepsilon \ln(t) =\int_a^{at} \frac{-\varepsilon}{x}\ dx\le\int_a^{at} \frac{f(x)}{x}\ dx\le\int_a^{at} \frac{\varepsilon}{x}\ dx=\varepsilon \ln(t).$$

Since we can make $\varepsilon \ln(t)$ as small as we want ($t$ is fixed and $\varepsilon >0$ is arbitrary) by choosing a large enough $N_{\varepsilon}$, we can conclude that the limit is $0$.